# Should Mathematica get a registered sign in the SE footer?

Tags: feature-request, footer

The banner for the *Mathematica*.SE follows the word *Mathematica* with a registered sign, ®, as it should because *Mathematica* is the registered trademark of Wolfram Research, Inc. But in the footer that appears on every page of all SE sites, *Mathematica* does not get an ®. Shouldn't this be corrected?

Comment: Hmm, maybe Mathematica is supposed to be the site's name? I see no reason why it shouldn't, since ExpressionEngline has an ® next to it. Maybe I'm missing something. +1 for now.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M. Yes, I saw that, too. It is what made me think that the footer should also show Mathematica ®. In the site's banner the name is given as Mathematica ®